# how to create array of instance of object Account using the keyboard input

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java.util.scanner

i have a program that create an array of Account object by asking the user to enter their properties than the system will make of these inserted input an array.

this is my code

## Account.java

```
package question1;

import java.util.Date;

public class Account {

    public int AccountNum;
    public double BALANCE;
    public Date OPENDATE;
    public String OwnerName;

    public Account() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Account(int accnum, double balance, Date opendate, String ownername) {

        this.AccountNum = accnum;
        this.BALANCE = balance;
        this.OPENDATE = opendate;
        this.OwnerName = ownername;

    }

    public int getAccountNum() {
        return AccountNum;
    }

    public void setAccountNum(int accountNum) {
        AccountNum = accountNum;
    }

    public double getBALANCE() {
        return BALANCE;
    }

    public void setBALANCE(double bALANCE) {
        BALANCE = bALANCE;
    }

    public Date getOPENDATE() {
        return OPENDATE;
    }

    public void setOPENDATE(Date oPENDATE) {
        OPENDATE = oPENDATE;
    }

    public String getOwnerName() {
        return OwnerName;
    }

    public void setOwnerName(String ownerName) {
        OwnerName = ownerName;
    }

    public double yearlyInterest(double balace) {
        return balace;
    }
}
```

## Bank.java

```
package question1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bank  {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>(4);

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(!sc.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("enter your balance");

            int b = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("enter your name");
            String s = sc.nextLine();



        }

    } 



}
```

i do not know how to continue in the Bank Class and how to create this array using the scanner.

if anyone can help me i will appreciate this.

Comment: why i got a down voting ???

Comment: Do you want he user to type in how many accounts that should be created?

Comment: welcome, because this is a very basic question, answered easily by a quickly search in Google.

Comment: @Hector if i did not search on google i would not be here asking this question any way thank you for your participation

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Do you wanna create new account?Y/N");
while(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
      //Get needed information. You shouldn't take account number from user. It must be generated
      System.out.println("Enter Name");
      String name = scanner.next();
      System.out.println("Enter Account Balance");
      float balance = scanner.nextFloat();
      ......    
      //create new instance of Account and set values
      Account acc = new Account();
      acc.setBalance(balance);
      .....

      //add instance to list
      accounts.add(acc);
      System.out.println("Do you wanna create new account?Y/N");
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution but it did not work as it should .... the result was  enter your name enter your balance ...after i enter nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you are studying for the exams of Lebanese army LOL anw this is the code bro.

AccountDriver

//Demonstrates the BankAccount and derived classes

import java.text.*;         // to use Decimal Format

public class AccountDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double put_in = 500;
    double take_out = 1000;

    DecimalFormat myFormat;
    String money;
    String money_in;
    String money_out;
    boolean completed;

    // to get 2 decimals every time
    myFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    //to test the Checking Account class
    CheckingAccount myCheckingAccount =
            new CheckingAccount ("Benjamin Franklin", 1000);
    System.out.println ("Account Number "
        + myCheckingAccount.getAccountNumber() +
        " belonging to " + myCheckingAccount.getOwner());
    money  = myFormat.format(myCheckingAccount.getBalance());
    System.out.println ("Initial balance = $" + money);
    myCheckingAccount.deposit (put_in);
    money_in = myFormat.format(put_in);
    money  = myFormat.format(myCheckingAccount.getBalance());
    System.out.println ("After deposit of $" + money_in
        + ",  balance = $" + money);
    completed = myCheckingAccount.withdraw(take_out);
    money_out = myFormat.format(take_out);
    money  = myFormat.format(myCheckingAccount.getBalance());
    if (completed)
    {
        System.out.println ("After withdrawal of $" + money_out
                + ",  balance = $" + money);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("Insuffient funds to withdraw $"
                + money_out + ",  balance = $" + money);
    }
    System.out.println();

    //to test the savings account class
    SavingsAccount yourAccount =
            new SavingsAccount ("William Shakespeare", 400);
    System.out.println ("Account Number "
            + yourAccount.getAccountNumber() +
            " belonging to " + yourAccount.getOwner());
    money  = myFormat.format(yourAccount.getBalance());
    System.out.println ("Initial balance = $" + money);
    yourAccount.deposit (put_in);
    money_in = myFormat.format(put_in);
    money  = myFormat.format(yourAccount.getBalance());
    System.out.println ("After deposit of $" + money_in
            + ",  balance = $" + money);
    completed = yourAccount.withdraw(take_out);
    money_out = myFormat.format(take_out);
    money  = myFormat.format(yourAccount.getBalance());
    if (completed)
    {
        System.out.println ("After withdrawal of $" + money_out
            + ",  balance = $" + money);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("Insuffient funds to withdraw $"
            + money_out + ",  balance = $" + money);
    }
    yourAccount.postInterest();
    money  = myFormat.format(yourAccount.getBalance());
    System.out.println ("After monthly interest has been posted,"
            + "balance = $" + money);
    System.out.println();


    // to test the copy constructor of the savings account class
    SavingsAccount secondAccount =
            new SavingsAccount (yourAccount,5);
    System.out.println ("Account Number "
            + secondAccount.getAccountNumber()+
            " belonging to " + secondAccount.getOwner());
    money  = myFormat.format(secondAccount.getBalance());
    System.out.println ("Initial balance = $" + money);
    secondAccount.deposit (put_in);
    money_in = myFormat.format(put_in);
    money  = myFormat.format(secondAccount.getBalance());
    System.out.println ("After deposit of $" + money_in
            + ", balance = $" + money);
    secondAccount.withdraw(take_out);
    money_out = myFormat.format(take_out);
    money  = myFormat.format(secondAccount.getBalance());
    if (completed)
    {
        System.out.println ("After withdrawal of $" + money_out
                + ",  balance = $" + money);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("Insuffient funds to withdraw $"
                + money_out + ",  balance = $" + money);
    }
    System.out.println();

    //to test to make sure new accounts are numbered correctly
    CheckingAccount yourCheckingAccount =
            new CheckingAccount ("Issac Newton", 5000);
    System.out.println ("Account Number "
            + yourCheckingAccount.getAccountNumber()
            + " belonging to "
            + yourCheckingAccount.getOwner());

}
}

BankAccount(Parent class)

//Defines any type of bank account

public abstract class BankAccount
{
// class variable so that each account has a unique number
protected static int numberOfAccounts = 100001;

// current balance in the account
private double balance;
// name on the account
private String owner;
// number bank uses to identify account
private String accountNumber;

//default constructor
public BankAccount()
{
    balance = 0;
    accountNumber = numberOfAccounts + "";
    numberOfAccounts++;
}

//standard constructor
public BankAccount(String name, double amount)
{
    owner = name;
    balance = amount;
    accountNumber = numberOfAccounts + "";
    numberOfAccounts++;
}

//copy constructor
public BankAccount(BankAccount oldAccount, double amount)
{
    owner = oldAccount.owner;
    balance = amount;
    accountNumber = oldAccount.accountNumber;
}

//allows you to add money to the account
public void deposit(double amount)
{
    balance = balance + amount;
}

//allows you to remove money from the account if
//enough money is available
//returns true if the transaction was completed
//returns false if the there was not enough money
public boolean withdraw(double amount)
{
    boolean completed = true;

    if (amount <= balance)
    {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }
    else
    {
        completed = false;
    }
    return completed;
}

//accessor method to balance
public double getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}

//accessor method to owner
public String getOwner()
{
    return owner;
}

//accessor method to account number
public String getAccountNumber()
{
    return accountNumber;
}

//mutator method to change the balance
public void setBalance(double newBalance)
{
    balance = newBalance;
}

//mutator method to change the account number
public void setAccountNumber(String newAccountNumber)
{
    accountNumber = newAccountNumber;
}
}
CheckingAccount

public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {

private double fee = .15;

private String accountNumber = getAccountNumber() + "-10";  

public CheckingAccount(String name, double amount) 
{

    super(name, amount);

    setAccountNumber(accountNumber);


}

public boolean withdraw(double amount)
{
    double finalAmount = amount + fee;

    super.withdraw(finalAmount);

    boolean completed = true;

    return completed;

}

}
And finally, SavingsAccount

public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount{

double rate = .025;

static int savingsNumber = 0;

private String accountNumber = super.getAccountNumber();


//Default constructor
public SavingsAccount(String name, double amount){

    super(name, amount);

    accountNumber = accountNumber + "-" + Integer.toString(savingsNumber);

}


//Copy constructor
public SavingsAccount(SavingsAccount oldAccount, double amount)
{           

    savingsNumber++;

    accountNumber = oldAccount.accountNumber + Integer.toString(savingsNumber);
owner = oldAccount.getOwner();
    balance = oldAccount.getBalance();
}


public void postInterest(){
    double interestAmount = getBalance() * .025/12;

    double finalAmount = getBalance() + interestAmount;

    setBalance(finalAmount);
}


public String getAccountNumber()
{
    return accountNumber;
}
}
```